# Bootstrap 3 in ASP.NET Web Forms not working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I browse (in IE 11) to a page with Localhost in URL (e.g. http://localhost:8070/MyApp/Login.aspx) everything works. The page is responsive and Bootstrap 3 classes work.

When I browse to the same page, in the same browser, using the server name (e.g. http://ServerName:8070/MyApp/Login.aspx) the Bootstrap classes are not used.

In Developer Tools, Network, I verified that in both cases, all scripts and stylesheets are loaded.

I traced this issue to the following difference in the Developer Tools DOM Explorer.  The Style pane in the case of running the page with Localhost has "@media all and (min-width:768px)" in many places.  But the Style pane, when executing the page with the ServerName has not references to "@media.."

This is the only difference.  Why? and what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have compatibility settings enabled for intranet pages. Disable that from internet explorer compatibility view settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if any of the media queries are malformed when on the server it will not recognize the rest. It was on odd occurrence, but maybe it's happening to you as well. Check your css against https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/. Make sure it doesn't find any errors. It's a shot in the dark but ya never know. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reckface's answer, I found that in IE 11 you may have to change the Document mode to something else. For me it was set to 7 by default. Setting it to 10 or higher fixed the issue my website was having when rendering.

To set the Document mode

1. Press F12 while in IE 11
2. Click on Emulator tab
3. Select the document mode from the dropdown.